# Jenkins 'agent: none' lightweight executor equivalent with scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

With Jenkins declarative syntax, it's possible to run parallel stages with no top-level agent. This ends up consuming two executors, since the top level agent is marked 'none':

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Run on parallel nodes') {
            parallel {
                stage('Do one thing') {
                    agent any
                    steps {
                        ...
                    }
                stage('Do another thing') {
                    agent any
                    steps {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

With scripted pipelines, which requires a top-level 'node' element, this is seemingly not possible. This ends up consuming three executors, even though only two are doing real work:

```
node {
  stage('Run on parallel nodes') {
    parallel ([
      'Do one thing': {
          node() {
            ...
          }
      },
      'Do another thing': {
          node() {
              ...
          }
      }
    ])
  }
}
```

---

Is a 'lightweight' top level executor possible with scripted pipelines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scripted pipelines don't require a top-level `node` allocation. This is just wrong and can be left out.

Comment: Good call, I'm not sure why I assumed a top-level node allocation is required, thanks!